# How to disable `autorun.inf` access on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mount, nautilus, compiz, autorun

Whenever I mount a filesystem, something tries to access a file named `autorun.inf` on this fresh mount.  How can I prevent Ubuntu 16.04 from doing this?  (FYI: I am logged in, Graphical session with Compiz.)

FYI:

Media access already is disabled via: System-Settings, Details, Removable Media.

Also I tried to follow all solutions on Ask Ubuntu (and probably some others) but nothing helped.  [My `FUSE` test filesystem](https://github.com/hilbix/nastysan) always shows these accesses to `autorun.inf`.

Here is a debug log ([source which outputs this](https://github.com/hilbix/nastysan/blob/0cd869419110ae2786c06f444050c8c07f4685c3/py/nastysan/__init__.py)):

```
./nastysan x >/dev/null
DEBUG:llfuse:Initializing llfuse
DEBUG:llfuse:Calling fuse_mount
DEBUG:llfuse:Calling fuse_lowlevel_new
DEBUG:llfuse:Calling fuse_set_signal_handlers
DEBUG:llfuse:Calling fuse_session_add_chan
DEBUG:llfuse:Calling fuse_session_loop_mt
INFO:nastysan:op access: 1 4
INFO:nastysan:op lookup: 1 b'.xdg-volume-info'
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op lookup: 1 b'autorun.inf'
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op opendir: 1
INFO:nastysan:op lookup: 1 b'autorun.inf'
```

But I want this accesses to `autorun.inf` (and if possible `.xdg-volume-info`, too) to not happen on `mount()` time.  What is the standard way to prevent Ubuntu from accessing new `mount()`s like this without explicit consent from the user?

Comment: Ever find an answer?

Comment: @RossRogers Not really.  AFAICS [one could write some SystemTap Probe](https://github.com/hilbix/tino/blob/master/howto/stap.md#fsyncstp) to suppress such annoyance.  But I haven't tried yet.